# Stabilizing split videos in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

I have a continuous shot video that is split into 2 parts (my camera splits them at 4GB) and want to apply the warp stabilizer to the whole video. Since the warp stabilizer is using analyzing them independently, the zoom factor is never the same.

I tried to manually determine the zoom factor of the stabilizer but there is no way of setting the actual zoom. I only can set the maximum zoom and an additional % of zoom. On top of that, the center of reference for the zoom is different in each clip even if I manage to hit the same zoom factor.

What's the best way to stabilize the whole shot? Is there a way to link them before applying the stabilizer? Or do I need to join them, export the sequence, re-import the result and then stabilize it?

Comment: Why do you need to split them in two? If there is other stuff in between, is it really important they have the exact same zoom factor (since there will be no visible jump between frames)? Also note that you can manually set a zoom factor using the warp stabilizer options.

Comment: It's split because the camera splits the files at 4GB. I don't want them to be split.

Comment: What kind of camera do you have? If you import the footage using Premiere's media browser, continuous sequences split by the camera  _should_ show up as a single file. See [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1468639) for some info. Of course there's a number of reasons for this not to work, ranging from deleting the metadata files created by the camera to the camera model being not supported by Premiere ...

Comment: It's a Canon 5D IV. I import the data with Lightroom.

Comment: You import the video files using Lightroom? What for, do you need the video files in Lightroom?

Comment: I do photo shoots where I take a couple of hundred photos and 3-4 short videos (Live music). I never even considered importing the videos with Premiere since I did not expect the result to be different. I will need to try that next time and see if that fixes the videos automatically.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, Lightroom just moves the files, it doesn't do any encoding conversion or something like that ... If this is a regular problem for you, you could look into getting a SDXC card, those will be formatted to exFat instead of FAT32 by your camera, so the videos won't be split at the 4GB mark. However, for your current problem, you should be able to apply the filter if you wrap your files in a nested sequence. I'm at work right now, I'll check that later and write a more detailed reply if no one has answered by then.